# numpy reshape: incompatible array size, when array grows too big?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, casting, reshape

I have the following code:

```
n=1000  
dset=np.fromfile(f,dtype='uint16',count=np.int64(n*dim_x*dim_y*dim_z*dim_c)
dset=np.reshape(dset,np.int64([n,dim_z,dim_y,dim_x,dim_c]))
```

sizes are like

```
print dim_x,dim_y,dim_z,dim_c
1536 800 7 1
```

The code works fine with n=500 , but with n=1000 I get

> C:\Users\maximih\AppData\Local\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python->2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.pyc in reshape(a, >newshape, order)
> 219     except AttributeError:
> 220         return _wrapit(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
> --> 221     return reshape(newshape, order=order)
> 222
> 223
>
> ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

I originally posted this as an issue on github, but closed, because I am unsure.... someone suggested to upgrade numpy but I am allready using '1.9.2'

I suggest that this is an overflow of some np.prod call. This function does indeed overflow , i tested it, thats why I tried to explicitly cast the product as int64....
Any suggestions?

Thanks
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I join all the people, that are too stupid to check their array sizes (Some would say of course, this was the problem, I suppose)...
np.fromfile does not complain, if  the count is > then the filesize, so I read in less data then I thought.